# Android Studio Emulator - IllegalArgumentException when taking screenshot

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, screenshot, illegalargumentexception

I am getting an `IllegalArgumentException` when trying to take a screenshot in Android Emulator (Take Screenshot button). I've tried reinstalling Android studio and downloading a new system image (API 31), but the issue persists. I am using Android studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1 and emulator API 31. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's fixed in Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 RC 1

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue after updating to Android Studio Giraffe. The issue has been resolved in [Android Studio Hedgehog](https://developer.android.com/studio/) which is now stable as of November 30, 2023.

Comment: Giraffe Patch 2 doesn't fix it either